# Stanford-nlp classifier out of memory for n-grams with n>1

Tags: memory, machine-learning, stanford-nlp

i am trying to run the [20 news text classification example](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier/20_Newsgroups) of the Stanford-nlp classifier with n-grams(n=>1,2,3) as features but i continue getting out of memory error. Following the properties that i am use and the command to run it:

```
2.useSplitWordNGrams=true
2.maxWordNGramLeng=3               
2.minWordNGramLeng=1               

java -mx1800m -cp $STANFORD_CLASSIFIER_JAR edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier \
   -trainFile 20news-devtrain.txt -testFile 20news-devtest.txt \
   -2.useSplitWords -2.splitWordsRegexp "\\s+" -prop 20news1.prop
```

For unigrams the program runs as expected. The problem is that i have only 4G memory available and i was wondering if it is possible to load big models like these one with such few memory.

I tried to reduce the size of the data by translating each word(after tokenization) of each article to a unique integer id by keeping a hash in memory with "word,id" pairs. This method manage to decrease the size 25% down, but stil didnt manage to built the bi-gram model classifier.

I would like to use the stanford-nlp on very large data(web pages) so i really need to know if i can get it running with a reasonable amount of memory. Any idea will be much appreciated!!

Cheers,
Dimitris

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the Stanford-NLP code, but I can answer generically about n-gram features. If your vocabulary has *v* items in it, then a naive bigram model has *v*^2 parameters (and a trigram model has *v*^3). What you should do is find the most discriminative bigrams, and use those as features, if you're sure you want n-gram features. Look at various [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) methods to do this.

Comment: Thats correct. Furthermore there is also the Zipfs law where we can skip almost the half features(singletons), without affecting classification performance.